# Where does VS 2015 pick up the KRE versions?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I've installed a bunch of KRE versions with KVM, from alpha1 to beta3. And also I'm aware that in VS 2012 CTP 6 I'm able to use a specific KRE version.

The problem is there's this web app based on beta2 while VS 2015 only lists beta3 (I believe beta3 is used by default if you don't specify), which causes the web app building failure.

For sure migrating the app from beta2 to beta3 will fix this issue. But why can't I see all the KRE versions installed with KVM in VS and select beta2 specifically from there? Where does VS 2015 pick up *its own* KRE versions? Is there any reason VS 2015 doesn't use the same KRE repository as KVM does?

Thanks

Comment: **Update** - Finally figured out that both VS 2015 CTP6 and KVM beta3 load KRE versions from a **NEW** location, which is **%userprofile%\.k** instead of previous **%userprofile%\.kre**.

Comment: I had a similar problem VS IDE was picking up all the references from %userprofile%\.kre while the packages were getting placed and the compiler was looking in %userprofile%\.k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a change in folder names, VS CTP6 and KVM beta3 cannot use previous versions of the runtime. If you still want beta2, you have to manually install a KVM and use it from console or downgrade VS.

Comment: Thanks for your clear clarification. So both VS 2015 and KVM are actually using the same KRE repository, or should I say VS 2015 calls KVM to manage KRE versions.

Comment: Oh, I spoke too soon. Looks like VS 2015 DOES load KRE versions from a different location, which is **%userprofile%\.k**.